# Create column from all possible combination of two columns in dataframe based on groupby in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a dataframe in like below

| id | group | log |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | UU1Q | 23 |
| 10 | UU1Q | 12 |
| 10 | UU2Q | 15 |
| 11 | UU2Q | 17 |
| 11 | UU3Q | 35.6 |
| 11 | UU1Q | 29.8 |
| 11 | UU1Q | 33 |
| 11 | UU1Q | 44 |
| 13 | UU2Q | 17.77 |
| 13 | UU2Q | 19.90 |
| 13 | UU2Q | 55 |
| 14 | UU3Q | 33 |
| 15 | UU3Q | 22 |

For Each ID and group I want to create all possible combination of log values present in the dataframe in a new column.
**Desired Output**

| id | group | log | new_col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | UU1Q | 23 | (23,23) |
| 10 | UU1Q | 12 | (23,12) |
| 10 | UU2Q | 15 | (15,15) |
| 11 | UU2Q | 17 | (17,17) |
| 11 | UU3Q | 35.6 | (35.6,35.6) |
| 11 | UU1Q | 29.8 | (29.8, 29.8) |
| 11 | UU1Q | 33 | (29.8,33) |
| 11 | UU1Q | 44 | (29.8,44) |
| 11 | UU1Q |  | (33,44) |
| 13 | UU2Q | 17.77 | (17.77,17.77) |
| 13 | UU2Q | 19.90 | (17.77,19.90) |
| 13 | UU2Q | 55 | (17.77,55) |
| 13 | UU2Q |  | (19.90,55) |
| 14 | UU3Q | 33 | (33,33) |
| 15 | UU3Q | 22 | (22,22) |

I used shift function but it is only generating combinations with next matching cell. I want to get all the possible combination in each group.
`dummy['new'] = dummy.groupby(['ID', 'group'])['log'].shift()`

Comment: @Ch3steR correction made

Comment: Also please avoid the `---` and `|` in text formatting

Comment: In your input, in the group for `10` and `UU1Q`, there are only 2 log values, which are `23` and `12`. In your output,  you have two combinations, which are `(23,23)` and `(23,12)`. What's the logic behind these 2 combination? Why you don't have `(12, 12)`. Do you really want `(23, 23)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is close what need - added all combinations and if one element per group is created tuple with same values:

```
from  itertools import  combinations

df = (df.groupby(['id','group'])['log']
        .apply(lambda x: list(combinations(x, 2)) if len(x) > 1 else [(*x, *x)])
        .explode()
        .reset_index(name='comb'))
print (df)
    id group           comb
0   10  UU1Q   (23.0, 12.0)
1   10  UU2Q   (15.0, 15.0)
2   11  UU1Q   (29.8, 33.0)
3   11  UU1Q   (29.8, 44.0)
4   11  UU1Q   (33.0, 44.0)
5   11  UU2Q   (17.0, 17.0)
6   11  UU3Q   (35.6, 35.6)
7   13  UU2Q  (17.77, 19.9)
8   13  UU2Q  (17.77, 55.0)
9   13  UU2Q   (19.9, 55.0)
10  14  UU3Q   (33.0, 33.0)
11  15  UU3Q   (22.0, 22.0)
```

Or is possible create same values tuples of first rows per ['id','group'] and join to DataFrame `df1` filled by combinations:

```
from  itertools import  combinations

df1 = (df.groupby(['id','group'])['log']
        .apply(lambda x: list(combinations(x, 2)))
        .explode()
        .dropna()
        .reset_index(name='comb'))

df2 = df.groupby(['id','group']).head(1).copy()
df2['comb'] = df2.pop('log').map(lambda x: (x,x))

df = pd.concat([df2, df1]).sort_values(['id','group'], ignore_index=True)
print (df)
    id group            comb
0   10  UU1Q    (23.0, 23.0)
1   10  UU1Q    (23.0, 12.0)
2   10  UU2Q    (15.0, 15.0)
3   11  UU1Q    (29.8, 29.8)
4   11  UU1Q    (29.8, 33.0)
5   11  UU1Q    (29.8, 44.0)
6   11  UU1Q    (33.0, 44.0)
7   11  UU2Q    (17.0, 17.0)
8   11  UU3Q    (35.6, 35.6)
9   13  UU2Q  (17.77, 17.77)
10  13  UU2Q   (17.77, 19.9)
11  13  UU2Q   (17.77, 55.0)
12  13  UU2Q    (19.9, 55.0)
13  14  UU3Q    (33.0, 33.0)
14  15  UU3Q    (22.0, 22.0)
```

Comment: could you please explain operations on df2 done two times in itertools solution?

Comment: @SameerKumarPandey - Sure - I can filter first rows per `id, group` groups by `df2 = df.groupby(['id','group']).head(1).copy()` and then create tuples by same values of column `log` - is used `df2.pop('log')` for use and drop column `log` with custom lambda function `.map(lambda x: (x,x))` for create tuples with same values for first and second value

Answer (score 0):

This will return the desired output:

```
df.groupby(['id','group'], as_index=False).agg({'log':lambda x: list(x)})


Output:

    id  group   log
0   10  UU1Q    [23.0, 12.0]
1   10  UU2Q    [15.0]
2   11  UU1Q    [29.8, 33.0, 44.0]
3   11  UU2Q    [17.0]
4   11  UU3Q    [35.6]
5   13  UU2Q    [17.77, 19.9, 55.0]
6   14  UU3Q    [33.0]
7   15  UU3Q    [22.0]
```

Comment: This is grouping the data in a single row for each combination. But I want entry for each binary combination for ex :- for (a, b, c) i want (a, b), (a,c) and (b, c) and my dataframe size can also increase after creating the groups